# Laravel - Why is there a timezone_type and timezone when I insert Carbon::now() on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel, php-carbon

When I echo `Carbon::now()`. It displays the datetime only. "2018-07-05 09:21:21"

But when I insert this on MongoDB, it becomes an Object;

```
{
    "date" : "2018-07-05 09:21:21.020981",
    "timezone_type" : 3,
    "timezone" : "UTC" 
}
```

I only want the data on `date`. Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

I tried doing this

```
$currentDateTime = strtotime(Carbon::now());

$request->merge([
    'dateSample' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDateTime)
]);
```

But it saves as `string` type. I need it to be `Date` type.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add your attributes to the `protected $dates` array in your model like this: protected `$dates = [ 'end_date' ];` Check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 5):

because when you `echo Carbon::now()` that time called `__toString` function 
Here is a code.

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->format(static::$toStringFormat);
}
```

If you use `dd(Carbon::now());` you must be see this result

```
{
    "date" : "2018-07-05 09:21:21.020981",
    "timezone_type" : 3,
    "timezone" : "UTC" 
}
```

when `echo Carbon::now();` that case you see result `Carbon::now()->__toString()` which is "2018-07-05 09:21:21"; 
**Edit**
For get `DateTime` object you can

```
$currentDateTime = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
$date = new DateTime($currentDateTime);
```

Comment: Ohh, that explains a lot. But that means I'll be inserting the `datetime` on a `string` type on MongoDB. How can I force that to be a `Date` type?

Comment: I dont understand question. Can you ask more explain?? You wont to set in db  2018-07-05 09:21:21 string??

Comment: \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

Comment: date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentDateTime) all time return string. Can you show `Date` class full name?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your database table column is set the type date `example_date` date DEFAULT NULL,

oops, my mistake you want use merge()

```
$request->merge([
    'dateSample' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
]);
```